# Invalid Column Name on Databases

Tags: c#, database

Screenshot showing column & column entry
[image: Screenshot showing column & column entry]

Hey all, I'm getting an error saying my column names are invalid. I know it's not the table that is wrong because it worked perfectly fine an hour ago. I tried different variations of the Id, issue, etc with no luck.

```
namespace Csis265.DAL
{
    public class BugMapper : BaseMapper
    {
        public BugMapper(SqlDataReader rdr) : base(rdr)
        { }

        public override object DoMapping()
        {
            logger.Debug("INSIDE BugMapper DoMapping() !!!");

            int id = GetInteger("ID");
            string issue = GetString("ISSUE");
            string resolution = GetString("RESOLUTION");
            int statusId = GetInteger("STATUS_ID");
            int priorityId = GetInteger("PRIORITY_ID");
            int softwareappId = GetInteger("SOFTWARE_APP_ID");
            DateTime dateCreated = GetDateTime("DATE_CREATED");
            DateTime dateResolved = GetDateTime("DATE_RESOLVED");

            Bug rtnObj = new Bug(id, issue, resolution,
                statusId, priorityId, softwareappId, dateCreated, dateResolved);

            logger.Debug($"INSIDE BugMapper DoMapping() {rtnObj.ToString()}");

            return rtnObj;
        }
    }
```

BUG CLASS - Nothing was touched besides the issue get/set. I originally had it as name instead of issue but have fixed that mistake

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using log4net;

namespace Csis265.Domain
{
    public class Bug : BaseObject
    {
        protected string issue;
        protected string resolution;
        protected int statusId;
        protected int priorityId;
        protected int softwareappId;
        protected Status status;
        protected Priority priority;
        protected SoftwareApp softwareapp;

        public Status Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { status = value; }
        }

        public Priority Priority
        {
            get { return priority; }
            set { priority = value; }
        }

        public SoftwareApp SoftwareApp
        {
            get { return softwareapp; }
            set { softwareapp = value; }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public string Issue
        {
            get { return issue; }
            set { issue = value; }
        }

        public string Resolution
        {
            get { return resolution; }
            set { resolution = value; }
        }

        public string StatusName
        {
            get { return Status.Name; }
        }

        public string PriorityName
        {
            get { return Priority.Name; }
        }

        public string SoftwareAppName
        {
            get { return SoftwareApp.Name; }
        }

        public Bug(int id, string issuse, string resolution, 
            int statusId, int priorityId, int softwareappId, 
            DateTime dateCreated, DateTime dateResolved) : base(id, dateCreated)
        {
            SetIssue(issue);
            SetResolution(resolution);
            SetStatusId(statusId);
            SetPriorityId(priorityId);
            SetSoftwareAppId(softwareappId);
        }

        public void SetIssue(string issue)
        {
            this.issue = issue;
        }

        private void SetSoftwareAppId(int softwareappId)
        {
            this.softwareappId = softwareappId;
        }

        private void SetPriorityId(int priorityId)
        {
            this.priorityId = priorityId;
        }

        private void SetStatusId(int statusId)
        {
            this.statusId = statusId;
        }

        private void SetResolution(string resolution)
        {
            this.resolution = resolution;
        }

        public string GetIssue()
        {
            return issue;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"BUG ID:{id} ISSUE: {issue} DTC: {dateCreated}";
        }

        public string GetResolution()
        {
            return resolution;
        }

        public int GetStatusId()
        {
            return statusId;
        }

        public int GetPriorityId()
        {
            return priorityId;
        }

        public int GetSoftwareAppId()
        {
            return softwareappId;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @sam It keeps saying invalid column name

Comment: undo the changes and see what broke it

Comment: For what column? `Status_ID`? Are you sure the data type is correct?

Comment: @Train it says all the columns are invalid when I try to run it

Comment: @MinhPhan Please paste your code instead of screenshots

Comment: Are you connecting to right database?

Comment: @vendettamit yes because I have other mappers set to different webpages and all of those are still working fine

Comment: Then you might want to check if the correct reader is being passed to the Mapper method.

Comment: @Jawad Code is posted now

Comment: Can you post your Bug class ?

Comment: @Jawad code is now posted

Comment: which line exactly does it throw the exception on

Comment: If you did a copy paste, then check your constructor. ```public Bug(int id, string issuse```. Extra s in the word issue

Answer (score 3):

line 20..

Change

```
int id = GetInteger("ID'");
```

to

```
int id = GetInteger("ID"); // Without the quote
```

Comment: Good catch but it still says invalid column name 'ID', 'Issue', etc etc